# How to get a number related to a string from HTML

Tags: c#, networking

In a website we have a code like this

```
<td>TheNumber</td>
<td>ACode</td>
<td style="width:350px;">A Special String For The Number</td>
```

I want to create an app that the users write the string and the app get 'TheNumber' from website according to the string.

Can we write an app like this in c#?

Comment: yes you can..start it and when you are stuck paste what you had done here..we will help as much as we can

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to manipulate HTML documents.

sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Load
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(@"<td>TheNumber</td><td>ACode</td><td style='width:350px;'>A Special String For The Number</td>");
        var div = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.Where(t => t.InnerText == "A Special String For The Number").ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        // Show info
        System.Console.WriteLine(div.PreviousSibling.InnerText);        
        System.Console.WriteLine(div.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't no what I'am looking for. How can I write code for get a value that have no Id and Value in web

Comment: thank you but i want to search just "A Special String For The Number" not the whole table code .